# Get remote ip of the client connecting to OpenVpn server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have setup a openvpn server, everything works fine. Now I am trying to log client-connect events. I am aware that there is client-connect directive in configuration file and each time a client connects the respective script is executed.

Now I want to log the public ip address and location of the client trying to connect to the server. How can I get client's original public ip address in this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the man page of openvpn

> -–client-connect script
>       Run scripton client connection. The script is passed the common name and IP address of the just-authenticated client as environmental
>   variable

So if your client-connect is a bash script, i will run export to see all environnement variables that are set in openvpn .

see

> SCRIPTING AND ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLES

`trusted_ip` and `untrusted_ip`

Comment: thanks, environment variable `trusted_ip` did the job